# can't call component constructor that has render function which is returned null in for loop react

Tags: reactjs

I don't know why component constructor doesn't called in for loop
following is my code

```
class Marker extends React.Component{
    constructor(pros){
       super(props)
       console.log('test')
    }
    render(){
        null
    }
}


class Map extends React.Component{
    render(){
        <div>{this._renderMarkers()}</div>
    }

    _renderMarkers(){
        this.state.markers.map((item, index)=> {
            return  (
                <div><Marker lat='xx' lng='xx' key={index}/></div>
            )
        }
    } 
}
```

when i return just one Marker in _renderMarkers(), i can show that marker constructor is called.

but in for loop, Marker constructor is never called.

how i solved the problem?? give me a good idea plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you never return your mapped array in your `_renderMarkers` function. If the React components are never rendered, their `constructor`s are never called.

```
_renderMarkers() {
    return this.state.markers.map((item, index)=> {
        return  (
            <div><Marker lat='xx' lng='xx' key={index}/></div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I think it's crazy to miss something like this. thank you